# Como fazer upload de arquivo xlsx com angular e php?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema financeiro para empresas de clientes que já possuo. Estou usando angular e php.
Nesse sistema, tenho uma parte que preciso importar dados em excel.
Estou tendo problemas para pegar o arquivo e o id da empresa para enviar a BD. 
OBS: Já tenho o código php que move o arquivo para outra pasta e transforma o xlsx em csv.

```
<button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
accept="*/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">Select File</button>

<?php
include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$id_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];

include_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");

$uploadDir = "uploadFile/";

$uploadfile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   echo "Dados pegos com sucesso.";
}else{
   echo "Não foi possível pegar arquivo";
}
?>
```

JS

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$window', 'Upload', function($scope, $window, Upload) {

    $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
        $scope.f = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        file.id_empresa = $window.localStorage.getItem("idemp");
        id_empresa = $window.localStorage.getItem("idemp");

        if (file) {
            console.log(file);
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/importaArquivo.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {'id_empresa': id_empresa}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                     evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }   
    }


}]);
```

Comment: De onde vem o id_empresa? O que vem no `$_FILES['arquivo']['name']`? É conveniente passar esta variável pelo `basename` para obteres só o nome do ficheiro.

Comment: O id_empresa vem do controller do angular.
Já no $_FILES['arquivo']['name'], não vem anda, pois não consigo pegar ele no angular e passar pro php, entende @foxtrot?
Esse $_FILES é de um sistema antigo que é só em php

Comment: Teu problema claramente é na parte javascript, por favor poste a função `salvarArquivo` para vermos como esta. E por favor leia isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, sempre que for perguntar formule um exemplo que possamos reproduzir o problema, vc presumiu que o problema era no PHP, mas entre o cliente-side e server-side podem haver muitas coisas, então sempre siga as dicas do link para ajudar as pessoas a lhe ajudarem

Comment: Coloco quei meus códigos javascript @GuilhermeNascimento.
Na verdade sei que o problema é no javascript mesmo. Desculpe eu não ter o colocado.

Comment: Este teu JavaScript não faz nada :/ só gera o console.log, se entendi o problema vc esta confundindo Ajax e envio normal.

Comment: Sim, por que quero ver o que vem em payload. Quero saber se o arquivo está vindo.

Answer (score 0):

Já percebi. Como tens não funciona.

Ou optas por utilizar apenas elementos nativos de HTML, e assim, ao fazeres o submit é enviado por POST o ficheiro, assim:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar conta" name="submit">
</form>
```

Desta forma, não é o AngularJS a receber o ficheiro e a ter de o re-enviar.

Se quiseres mesmo utilizar AngularJS, tens por exemplo o [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) em que podes fazer pre validações do lado do cliente, como o tamanho do ficheiro ou tipo, e depois podes usar o `Upload.upload()` para re-enviar para o servidor todos os dados. Tens [aqui um exemplo de utilização](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644702/155905).

Comment: Desculpe, mas achei bem complexo esse exemplo. Digo, a parte do JS.

Comment: Vou tentar seguir os exemplos.

Comment: Estou conseguindo. O problema agora é como pegar o arquivo e o id, que estou passando, no php

Comment: já consigo enviar o arquivo pro php, porém, não consigo pegar. E acredito que eu esteja enviando do js para o php